# Transfer Elden Ring save files to another account

Tags: steam, elden-ring

I wanted to figure out how to transfer my game save on one account to another Steam account with a different Steam id. I was able to find something very similar with Sekiro using this method [Sekiro account transfer tutorial](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/348146/how-to-transfer-your-sekiros-save-file-to-a-new-account), but the location for the account A and account B hex steamid is different on Elden Ring. Hopefully someone can help.